# How can I address a dynamic list item by its content with CSS? [Not possible just with CSS]

Tags: css

I want to add a background color to a dynamic list item of the popup pane of the Thunderbird extension "Check and Send".

[popup pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7hwu.png)

The content of the first element is the sender address which changes depending on the selection when composing a message.

I found this HTML for this part of the pane in the extension's code

```
<!-- Identity -->
    <div id="identityArea">
      <h3 class="titleline-simple" l10n-tag="casPopupIdentity"></h3>
      <ul>
        <li class="dia_list" id="identityName"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

The sender address must be added with JavaScript code which I don't understand.

I want to have different background colors depending on the content of the element.

I can easily address this element with CSS and add a fix background color

```css
li#identityName.dia_list {
   background-color: rgb(0,0,206) !important;
   color: white !important;
}
```

but I don't know how I can have different background colors for different sender addresses.

For the elements of a different extension this works:

```css
menuitem[label="name1 <address1@gmx.de>"],
#msgIdentity[label="name1 <address1@gmx.de>"]{
   background-color: rgb(0,0,206) !important;
   color: white !important;
}
menuitem[label="name2 <address2@gmx.de>"],
#msgIdentity[label="name2 <address2@gmx.de>"]{
   background-color: rgb(255,255,0) !important;
}
...
```

but this does not work for the list element. I also tried `value` and `content` instead of `label` but neither works.

Is there a way to address the list element by its content?

Comment: What is happening in the different extension is that the `label` attribute is set and that is used in the css with the attribute selector (code in square brackets). If there is any attribute being set containing the address information, you can do something similar, otherwise you have to learn some JavaScript. In particular the `.innerHTML` property would be handy here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment of mrmonsieur it is not possible just with CSS.

> What is happening in the different extension is that the label attribute is set and that is used in the css with the attribute selector (code in square brackets). If there is any attribute being set containing the address information, you can do something similar, otherwise you have to learn some JavaScript. In particular the .innerHTML property would be handy here.

JavaScript is needed to address the content of the item.